# Bower is not working

Tags: macos, npm, bower

My bower was working fine. Then yesterday, the internet here is so slow, and I was installing bootstrap and font-awesome.

Bootstrap is successfully installed, however font-awesome cannot be installed. Then my bower went wrong. I tried uninstall it and re-install it, it didn't work.

I now got the dependencies in bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"}
```

The error is :

```
localhost:confusion leo$ sudo npm install -g bower
/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/bin/bower -> /Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib
└── bower@1.7.9 

localhost:confusion leo$ bower install
/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:54
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/leo/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
    at readCachedConfig (/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
    at defaultConfig (/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/leo/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.0/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

I really need some help here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

Here is the fix, run below commands. it should work.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config
```